# Calculate Business Working Days exclude weekends

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to calculate working days and exclude weekends for an updated column Invoice_Date_to_Scan_Start_Date_Cal. I used to following code to get the result :

```
UPDATE FBL1IN_working
SET FBL1IN_working.Invoice_Date_to_Scan_Start_Date_Cal 
 = (datediff (DD, Doc_Date, Scan_Start_Date_Calc) +1) 

-(datediff (wk, Doc_Date, Scan_Start_Date_Calc) *2)

-(case when datename(dw, Doc_Date ) = 'Sunday' then 1 else 0 end)

-(case when datename(dw, Scan_Start_Date_Calc) = 'Saturday' then 1 else 0 end)
```

However, I noticed, there is a difference of one or two days counts in some of the calculated field (`Invoice_Date_to_Scan_Start_Date_Cal`). For example:

`Doc_Date = 2019-05-02` and
`Scan_Start_Date_Calc = 2018-11-19`
Hence, the `Invoice_Date_to_Scan_Start_Date_Cal` result should be `-119`. But with the above code, I am getting the result of `-117`. I do not know where the mistake is in that code. Could anyone please help me on this.

Thank you.

Comment: Please, provide a sample data and the expected results.

Comment: I am getting the result as `-118`. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=6556d1f2df2d8c12916d0605dafb9dd9

Comment: why don't you build your own calendar table and use it ?

Comment: Are you looking to exclude only Saturday and Sunday from a date range?

Comment: @mkRabbani yes only need to exclude saturday and sunday

Answer (score 0):

If you are only looking for exclude weekends from a data range, you can try this below code-

```
DECLARE @D1 DATETIME = '20190601'
DECLARE @D2 DATETIME = '20190611'
DECLARE @LoopCount INT = (SELECT DATEDIFF(DD,@D1,@D2))

DECLARE @TempTable TABLE
(
    date date
)

WHILE @LoopCount >= 0
BEGIN
   -- Checking not in (1,7) will exclude Suturday and Sunday from the counting
   IF DATEPART(dw,(DATEADD(DD,-@LoopCount,GETDATE()))) NOT IN (1,7)
   BEGIN 
        INSERT INTO @TempTable (date)
        VALUES (DATEADD(DD,-@LoopCount,GETDATE()))
    END
    SET @LoopCount = @LoopCount - 1
END


SELECT COUNT(*) total_working_days
FROM @TempTable
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a function online that solves my problem. It acts the same as NETWORKDAYS in Excel. Posting it here, perhaps it can help others who are having the same question.

CREATE function [dbo].[NetWorkDays](

@StartDate datetime

,@EndDate datetime

) returns int as begin

declare

@result int

,@StartDate2 datetime

,@EndDate2 datetime

,@DateSwap1 datetime

,@DateSwap2 datetime

,@ReturnNegative BIT

set @DateSwap1 = @StartDate

set @Dateswap2 = @EndDate

SET @ReturnNegative = 0

IF @EndDate < @StartDate

BEGIN

SET @ReturnNegative = 1

SET @StartDate = @Dateswap2

SET @EndDate = @DateSwap1

END

set @StartDate2 = dateadd(d,8-datepart(dw, @StartDate), @StartDate)

set @EndDate2 = dateadd(d,1-datepart(dw ,@EndDate), @EndDate)

set @result = datediff(d, @StartDate2, @EndDate2) * 5 / 7

- datediff(d, @StartDate, @StartDate2) - 1
- datediff(d, @EndDate2, @EndDate)
- case when datepart(dw,@StartDate) = 1 then 1 else 0 end
- case when datepart(dw,@EndDate) = 7 then 1 else 0 end

if @ReturnNegative = 1

BEGIN

SET @result = @result * -1

END

return @result

end

GO

Comment: FYI, this function covers minus days as well.